# SQL join two tables using the minimum value from second table

Tags: sql, join, db2, min

I have T1

```
ID STATUS
1  NEW
2  NEW
```

I have T2

```
T1ID  OWNER  OWNDATE

1      A      01.01.2017 10:00:00
1      B      02.02.2017 10:00:00
1      C      03.03.2017 10:00:00
2      B      02.02.2017 10:00:00
2      C      03.03.2017 10:00:00
```

Since A for ID 1 has the minimum OWNDATE and since B for ID 2 has the minimum OWNDATE

I want to get as result

```
1  NEW  A
2  NEW  B
```

But after the join I am not sure where to put MIN so I could find the minimum from two tables

```
SELECT 
    T1.ID, T1.STATUS, T2.OWNER
FROM 
    T1 
JOIN 
    T2 ON T1.ID = T2.T1ID
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please tag the DBMS you are using, eg MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle and if known the version number too. Some flavours of SQL allow methods which could give more efficient answers.

Comment: I did it now - db2. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below is a solution in plain SQL, using a subquery, it should work on most databases.

```
SELECT 
    T1.ID, T1.STATUS, T2.OWNER
FROM 
    T1 
JOIN 
    T2
ON T1.ID = T2.T1ID 
   AND t2.owndate = (
       select min( owndate ) FROM t2
       where t2.T1ID = t1.id
)
```

Comment: I have a question, In the subquery, why do you use a where? I mean related to the performance?

Answer (score 1):

In most RDBMS you can use Windows analytical functions

```
SELECT T1.ID,
      T1.STATUS,
      T.OWNER
FROM T1
  INNER JOIN
(SELECT t2.*,
      row_number() over(partition BY t1id
                        ORDER BY owndate) AS seq
  FROM t2
 ) t 
   ON t1.id=t.t1id
   AND t.seq=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.*, t3.OWNER
from t1
inner join lateral 
(
    select * from t2
    where t1.id=t2.T1ID
    order by t2.OWNDATE
    fetch first rows only
) t3 on 1=1
```